# What is the _ mean in this Regular Expression?

Tags: regex

This regular expression is the part of `(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*` email address validation regular expression. What kind of patterns does this regular expression generate or accept?

Comment: `_` is not a regex metacharacter. it's just an underscore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex will match underscores (the _), letters a to z, numbers 0-9, and dashes.

---

```
[A-Z]
```

Matches a single character, which can be any letter from A-Z

```
[A-Z]+
```

Matches ONE OR MORE characters, which can be any letter from A-Z

```
[A-Z]*
```

Matches ZERO OR MORE characters, which can be any letter from A-Z

```
[A-Za-z]
```

Matches a single character, which can be any letter from A-Z or a-z (Upper or lower case letters)

```
[0-9]
```

Matches any number from 0 to 9

```
[a-z0-9_]
```

Matches any character that is a letter from a to z, a number from 0-9 or an underscore

```
[abc]
```

Matches any character that is an a, b or c.

Comment: I need some patterns to understand this! would you please write 2 or 3

Comment: @JeloMelo Added a bunch of examples. Also check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for more info

Answer (score 2):

The part inside the brackets is a character group. It matches `_`, a to z, 0 to 9 and `-`.

Comment: what about \. then ? could it generate patterns like ._abc ?

Comment: @JeloMelo: Not clear what you are asking. I suggest you first learn the basics: http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: would you please generate some strings using this RE?

Comment: @JeloMelo: You can test that regular expression yourself: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: In Regular expressions, . is a metacharacter that matches 'any character except newline'. But if you want to match a dot specifically, you use an escape character like this: \.

So if you have 2 strings '._abc', . will match every character, but \. will only match the dot (first character of string)

Comment: Also, Regular expressions only match string patterns, they do not 'generate patterns'. That's just not how they work, in case you assumed so.

Answer (score 0):

It will match a string with `an underscore(_), a hyphen(-), letters a to z, numbers 0 to 9 in any order and of any number from 1 to infinity`.